# submit payload nonce to server Braintree SDK Paypal ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

Im uisng [Braintree Paypal SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/braintree)  to render paypal button in form with hosted feilds. however, I cannot figure out how to submit nonce to server. how do i do that in this section?.

```
onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        return paypalCheckoutInstance.tokenizePayment(data)
          .then(function (payload) {
            // Submit `payload.nonce` to your server

        //console.log (payload.nonce)  
  });
},
```

my controller action is

```
def payment
  Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            amount: current_order.subtotal,
            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce], 
            :options => {
              :submit_for_settlement => true},
          )
  response = {:success => result.success?}          
  if result.success?
    response[:transaction_id] = result.transaction.id
    current_order.update(status: "purchased")
    ReceiptMailer.purchase_order(current_passenger, 
      current_order).deliver_now 
  redirect_to root_path, 
    notice: "Thank you for booking, Please check your email for invoice"
  session.delete(:cart_id)

  elsif result.transaction
    redirect_to cart_path, alert: "something went wrong, your transactions was not successful!"
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to generate a request in javascript to pass the payment nonce to your server. Here's a simple example of generating a request using jQuery's ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/payment",
  data: { payment_method_nonce: payload.nonce }
})
```